# Is the sentence "How much were your shares diluted?" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is the sentence "How much were your shares diluted?" correct?

Should it be "How much were your shares diluted to"?

Comment: The first is correcter.

Comment: Why? I think "Your shares were diluted xxxx" isn't correct, is it?

Comment: More correct is more correct.

Answer (score 8):

They're both correct. And so is

> How much were your shares diluted ***by***?

Incidentally, the answer to

> How much were your shares diluted?

would be *My shares were diluted to 40% of their original value.* or *My shares were diluted by 60%*. Simply giving a quantity would be ambiguous.

In contrast, the answers to

> How much were your shares diluted by?

and

> How much were your shares diluted to?

could be answered with a quantity (like 60%, for example) without any ambiguity.

Comment: Strictly, *"By how much were your shares diluted?"*

Comment: If the shares were halved the by or to becomes obsolete. Answer could be half ;)

Comment: `half` still represents a quantity.